# Neural Network or Differentiable Graph Matching

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, graph-theory, graph-neural-network

**Searching for:**

Neural Network solutions or implementations (learnable algorithm) for inexact graph matching.

**Graph matching:**

Given two graphs GM = (VM , EM) and GD = (VD, ED), with |VM| = |VD|, the problem is to find a one-to-one mapping f : VD → VM such that (u, v) ∈ ED iff (f(u), f(v)) ∈ EM .

Inexact graph matching means that it is not possible to find an isomorphism between the two graphs to be matched. This is the case when the
number of vertices is different in both the model and data graphs, as found in many imaging problems.

**I am aware of:**

- https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6702-differentiable-learning-of-submodular-models.pdf
- http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7505936

**Advice:**

On any papers, algorithms, prefarably implemented (GitHub) that deal with learnable graph matching. This is to be  used in an optic flow Neural Network approach.